# How to change value of input?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I'm automating the tests of an website but I'm having trouble updating the value of an input. If I change the value it seems like the value I try to update is not updated in the active DOM which results that nothing happens after I submit.

I've even tried inspect element and changed the value manually and it still doesn't work.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript(
  "document.getElementById('ScheduleTime').setAttribute('value','2020-01-01 00:00')"
);

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(text(),'Submit')]")).Click();
```

Comment: It should work if the textbox was not disabled, also give a try like jse.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ScheduleTime').value='2020-01-01 00:00')");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using native JS, changing the `value` can be done using `element.value` here:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('ScheduleTime').value='2020-01-01 00:00'");
```

try it.

Also make sure that your `input` element is not disabled.

Answer (score 2):

First off, don't set the value using JSE. No user will do this and this is likely what is causing you problems. Setting values using JSE also goes around any events or JS handling of inputs that will make your inputs skip error checking, automatic formatting, etc.

Selenium has a built-in method for handling this, `.sendKeys()`. I don't know what language you are using but below is a Java example. All language bindings should have the equivalent that will be documented in the official docs. I recommend you look at them there and use them instead of JSE.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ScheduleTime")).sendKeys("2020-01-01 00:00");
```